# How to make Maya colorSliderGrp's change command execute only once when picking color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya

I am trying to work on a script to do the following:
Whenever the user picks a color from the *Maya UI*, it prints the color value.

I have a simple code like this

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.colorSliderGrp(cc = lambda *args: printColor())

cmds.showWindow()

def printColor():
    print ('color')
```

When I run this, a color slider group shows up in a window as expected. Now I click on the color swatch and change color, and it prints `'color'` as expected. But, when I move my cursor away (so the color picker goes away), it executes the `printColor()` function again (prints 'color' again).

What can I do to make it execute the `printColor()` function just once in the color-picking process?

Comment: I fear there is no much what you can do. Can't you design your script in a way it doesn't matter if the color is set twice?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is what I had to do actually. Instead of using a colorSliderGrp, I used a button command and color the button. When user clicks on the button, it opens a Maya colorEditor to pick the color.